# Select Max and Min datetime for distinct user

Tags: mysql

I have a record as below

```
ID(int)      DATA_ORA(timestamp)     BADGE  LETTORE       
   1         2017-04-01 09:30:00       1       1    
   2         2017-04-01 12:30:00       1       2    
   3         2017-04-01 13:30:00       1       1    
   4         2017-04-01 18:30:00       1       2    
   5         2017-04-01 09:30:00       2       1    
   6         2017-04-01 18:30:00       2       2    
   7         2017-04-02 09:30:00       1       1    
   8         2017-04-02 18:30:00       1       2
   9         2017-04-03 09:30:00       3       1    
   10        2017-04-03 12:30:00       3       2    
   11        2017-04-03 13:30:00       3       1    
   12        2017-04-03 18:30:00       3       2
```

I want to get the first access time and the last daily logout time (for each day) for each individual user (badge).

How I can do this?

The record I wish to as below

```
ID(int)      DATA_ORA(timestamp)     BADGE  LETTORE       
   1         2017-04-01 09:30:00       1       1        
   4         2017-04-01 18:30:00       1       2    
   5         2017-04-01 09:30:00       2       1    
   6         2017-04-01 18:30:00       2       2    
   7         2017-04-02 09:30:00       1       1    
   8         2017-04-02 18:30:00       1       2
   9         2017-04-03 09:30:00       3       1      
   12        2017-04-03 18:30:00       3       2
```

Is it possible to do that? Thanks.

NOTE: ID are auto-incremented and LETTORE 1 is entry and LETTORE 2 is exit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it grouping by date, badge and lettore like:

```
SELECT date(DATA_ORA),badge,lettore, case when lettore=1 then min(time(data_ora))
                                          when lettore=2 then max(time(data_ora))
                                          else 0
                                     end
FROM table1
group by date(DATA_ORA),badge,lettore
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a join  with subquery for badge 1 and badge 2

```
select t1.badge, min_dat, nax_date
from  (
  select  badge, min_(data_ora) min_data
  from my_table
  where lettore  = 1 
  group by badge 
) t1 
INNER JOIN  (
 select  badge, max_(data_ora) max_data
  from my_table
  where lettore  = 2
  group by badge 
) t2  ON t1.badge = t2.badge
```

Answer (score 0):

try below using correlated subquery and union all

```
select * from tablename a
where DATA_ORA in (select min(DATA_ORA) from tablename b where a.badge=b.badge)
union 
select * from tablename a
where DATA_ORA in (select max(DATA_ORA) from tablename b where a.badge=b.badge)
```

Answer (score 0):

I like @fa06 answer, but he misses, that you want the data daily.
so try this:

```
select * from t1 a
where DATA_ORA in (select min(DATA_ORA) from t1 b where a.badge=b.badge GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATA_ORA, '%Y%m%d'))
union
select * from t1 a
where DATA_ORA in (select max(DATA_ORA) from t1 b where a.badge=b.badge GROUP BY DATE_FORMAT(DATA_ORA, '%Y%m%d'));
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is the executed version of your table and query that gives output in the order you needed, on [DB-fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/9oMiUughLV88ub2Mahe7vG/0).
Try this query:

```
select * from EntryExitLogs where id in
    (select id from EntryExitLogs where (badge,data_ora)= any 
    (select badge,min(data_ora)from EntryExitLogs group by date(data_ora),badge))
    union
    (select * from EntryExitLogs where id in
    (select id from EntryExitLogs where (badge,data_ora)= any 
    (select badge,max(data_ora)from EntryExitLogs group by date(data_ora),badge)))
    order by id;
```

I think its better to make use of the ID column for selecting the rows, because the timestamp column contains duplicates.